# How actually Serial voting works? I lost reputation because of other user

Tags: support, serial-voting

Before some days I got notification from stack-overflow said "Serial upvoting reversed" and it has done (minus)-65 from my total reputation. I do not know who has serial voted to my questions and answers. I have read "Learn more" link of voting reverse but still confuse.

As far as I know it is not my fault that some one is doing serial voting on my questions and answers and I am getting reputation. So will stack-overflow return and do (Plus)+65 reputation which I have lost because of serial voting?

Please help to understand serial voting mechanism and about my lost reputation.

Comment: It just took away reputation you shouldn't have gotten in the first place. It corrected your reputation back to normal. You're not being punished, your reputation has just been corrected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As far as I know it is not my fault that some one is doing serial voting on my questions and answers and I am getting reputation. So will stack-overflow return and do (Plus)+65 reputation which I have lost because of serial voting?

Someone came and upvoted your content based on *you*, not on the content itself. That's what we call serial voting (there are cases where the reverse happens - people get lots of their posts downvoted, sometimes as revenge).

We specifically don't want that - posts should be voted upon based on the post value, not because of who posted them.

As such, when serial voting is detected, it is reversed. As if it never happened.

So, no - it may not be your fault, but this is also rep that shouldn't have been earned in the first place. So it will **not** be refunded.